# How to import a PHP file to another computer?

Tags: php, sql, json, ajax, web-services

I am working on a project with PHP server and I have no previous experience, so I will try to explain myself in the best way!
After I built my website and put the project in the XAMPP folder in order for the PHP browser to run, I had to also download the XAMPP control panel and run APACHE.
My question is how do I give permission to my team to also be able to open the site without downloading XAMPP and to belong to the server I created in PHPmyadmin, do I need an external server? Or is there another way? I would appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: [Search for static ip](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+static+ip&oq=what+is+static+ip) and [how to turn pc into a server](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+turn+pc+into+a+server) or  [buy a hosting](https://www.google.com/search?q=web+site+hosting)

Comment: `how do I give permission to my team...` on the same local network or across the internet? The former is easy, the latter has many potential security issues and probably not something for someone with limited knowledge

Comment: If you meant my same local server, then I did use ngrok, which makes the site behave as if it were on a public server.
I've been on this for a few days now and I'm learning on my own. I'd love to know more about a server that's really public, and I'd love to know if the company I work with assigns me their server, is it complicated after I wrote the code in php or is it just a matter of adding a few lines of code? thank you!